# Removing dynamically created tabs in jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

How do I remove tabs that were created dynamically using the jQuery UI library? It doesn't seem to mention anything about deleting tabs in the documentation for the library. I need to be able to delete the currently active tab, and to delete all tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You must now remove the HTML that renders the tab and panel itself and refresh the tabs:

```
function removeTab(tabId) {
  var tabIdStr = "#tabs-" + tabId

  // Remove the panel
  $( tabIdStr ).remove();
  // Refresh the tabs widget
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );

  // Remove the tab
  var hrefStr = "a[href='" + tabIdStr + "']"
  $( hrefStr ).closest("li").remove()
}
```

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamically-remove-tab

Comment: Oh I see, there's no method to do it in the library. 

In this example how can I get the tabId of the currently active tab?

Comment: After a bit of research i found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/k44Wk/1/) working example that perfectly shows all the process to do it!